# What is the time complexity of Array.sort?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

So i'm doing work where time complexity of code is a factor, and was just wondering what the complexity of Array.sort was? would this be like brute force/quadratic time complexity if I used it on an array?

Comment: The standard Java sort methods are QuickSort implementations. Generally speaking, it's `n log n`, but it could be `n^2` in the worst case.

Comment: One more thing to note is that if you have an array of objects, `Arrays.sort` is actually an implementation of TimSort instead of a QuickSort implementation. TimSort has an average (and worst) case of `n log n`, and is used because it's a *stable* sort.